# How to fit flextable to the width of the side borders in the word_document output? Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, flextable

I use `flextable()` in Rmarkdown for creating tables. I knit my code to word_document output. Does anyone have an idea how to fit the width of the table not to the content, but to the width of the side borders in the word_document output?

````
---
title: ""
output: word_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(flextable)
library(dplyr)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
head(cars)%>%
  flextable()%>%
  theme_box()%>%
  autofit()

```
````

Below I am attaching two pictures:

- the first - what my code produces, [image: This is the results]
- the second - what I wanted to produce [image: This is I need].

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to fit column widths based on column content and side borders in the word_document output

````
---

title: ""
output: word_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(flextable)
library(dplyr)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.


```{r cars}
 i = 16.5 # width of the side borders in the word_document output (in centimeters)
 w = i*0.3937 # width of the side borders in the word_document output (in inches)
 
df <- data.frame('model' = rownames(mtcars), mtcars[1:5])
t<-flextable(head(df,3))
t #not fitted table, all cols have the same base widths
t<-autofit(t)
t #auto-fitted, cols have the widths based on col content
#get column widths proportions from auto-fitted table
auto_widths <- dim(t)$widths/sum(dim(t)$widths)
# fit col widths based on col content and side borders in the word_document output
t<-width(t,  width=w*auto_widths)
t
```
````

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [manro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70356269/14807779) solution, I write a code that makes a table with a given width, no matter how many columns there are in the table. It was also my goal, which I may not have clearly explained in my question.

````
```{r cars}
 i = 16.5 # width of the side borders in the word_document output (in centimeters)
 w = i*0.3937 # width of the side borders in the word_document output (in inches)
 
    # Table 1 with 2 columns 
    head(cars,3) %>% 
      flextable %>%
      width(., width = (w/(ncol(cars)))) %>% 
      theme_box() 
       
    # Table 2 with 5 columns
    head(iris,3) %>% 
      flextable %>%
      width(., width = (w/(ncol(iris)))) %>% 
      theme_box() 
```
````

[image]

Comment: Nice, your solution is more precise, "+1" ;)

Answer (score 1):

Look [there](https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/reference/fit_to_width.html), David Gohel made a nice function for this task :)

**An example for you:**

````
```{r cars}
head(cars) %>% 
  flextable %>%
  width(., width = 3.35) %>% 
  theme_box() 
```
````

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, your suggestion was very helpful! However, I was looking for a solution that would not depend on the number of columns in the table. Based on your suggestion, I have written a code that does exactly what I wanted: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70358715/14807779.

Comment: Hi, monro! Here are more useful solution for fitting `flextable()` in [tag:r-markdown] word_document output: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70374586/14807779

Because I work a lot with tables in MS Word, I hope that in the future something like this will be able in [tag:flextable] package as a function.