# flextable width for rmarkdown html document

Tags: r, r-markdown, flextable, officer

When I create a `html` document with `rmarkdown`, I can `flextable::autofit` table 1 below to be presented in a correct manner but when I do the same for table 2, it doesn't work, does anyone know why?

As a fix, I tried extracting the `width` (using `flextable_dim`) of the columns used in table 1 and used that for table 2 but it seems to ignore that argument when it is rendered.

````
---
title: "tmp"
output: html_document
---


```{r, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE, results = "hide", fig.keep = "none"}
library(flextable)
library(officer)
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- structure(list(Variable = "this is a variable name for table 1", year = "", 
    `1` = "3221605", `2` = "3978169", `3` = "3398549", 
    `4` = "3339557", `5` = "3540978", `6` = "3480641", 
    `7` = "3454676", `8` = "3437130", `9` = "3640963", 
    `10` = "3891966", `11` = "3873802", `12` = "3834393", 
    `13` = "3088655", `14` = "3280407", `15` = "3505542"), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


df2 <- structure(list(Variable = "this is a variable name for table 2", 
    place_holder = "", w1 = "2.1 (1-4)", w2 = "2.1 (1-4)", 
    w3 = "1.2 (1-4)", w4 = "2 (1-4)", w5 = "1 (1-4)", 
    w6 = "1 (1-3)", w7 = "1 (1-3)", w8 = "1 (1-3)", 
    w9 = "1 (1-3)", w10 = "1 (1-3)", w11 = "1 (1-4)", 
    w12 = "2 (1-4)", w13 = "2 (1-5)", w14 = "2 (1-4)", 
    w15 = "2 (1-4)"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```



table 1

```{r tab1, include = TRUE, echo = FALSE, eval = T, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE}
header_names <- setNames(c("Variable", "level", 1990:2014),
                         names(df1))
ft1 <- flextable(df1) %>% 
  align_text_col(align = "center") %>% 
  align(i = NULL, j = 1, align = "left", part = "body") %>% 
  bold(part = "header") %>%  # bold header
  set_header_labels(values = header_names) %>% 
  bold(j = c(1, 2)) %>% 
  autofit() 
ft1
flextable_dim(ft1)
```

table 2

```{r tab2, include = TRUE, echo = FALSE, eval = T, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE}
header_names <- setNames(c("Variable", "level", 1990:2014),
                         names(df2))
ft2 <- flextable(df2) %>% 
  align_text_col(align = "center") %>% 
  align(i = NULL, j = 1, align = "left", part = "body") %>% 
  bold(part = "header") %>%  # bold header
  set_header_labels(values = header_names) %>% 
  bold(j = c(1, 2)) %>% 
  autofit()
  #width of each column in table 1
  #16.51252/17 = 0.9713247
  #width(width = 0.9713247)
  #set_table_properties(layout = "autofit") 
ft2
#flextable_dim(ft)
```

table 2 with width of table 1:

```{r tab2-1, include = TRUE, echo = FALSE, eval = T, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE}
header_names <- setNames(c("Variable", "level", 1990:2014),
                         names(df2))
ft2 <- flextable(df2) %>% 
  align_text_col(align = "center") %>% 
  align(i = NULL, j = 1, align = "left", part = "body") %>% 
  bold(part = "header") %>%  # bold header
  set_header_labels(values = header_names) %>% 
  bold(j = c(1, 2)) %>% 
  #autofit()
  #width of each column in table 1
  #16.51252/17 = 0.9713247
  width(width = 0.9713247)
  #set_table_properties(layout = "autofit") 
ft2
#flextable_dim(ft)
```
````

different widths:

[image]

Does anyone have a fix to make table 2 the same width as table 1 (so values in table 2 are not over two lines)? I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70355001/how-to-fit-flextable-to-the-width-of-the-side-borders-in-the-word-document-outpu/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57175351/flextable-autofit-in-a-rmarkdown-to-word-doc-causes-table-to-go-outside-page-mar/) but those options don't seem to work for me as the `width` argument doesn't seem to change anything in the `html` output.

thanks

edit: you can increase the entire width of the html document using this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70841086/4083743) but it still doesnt answer the above question.

Answer (score 0):

The long numbers you are trying to display in the table seem to be the problem. If you try reducing the font in the body, you will see this. Replace the `autofit()` line for the first table with

```
  fontsize(size = 7, part = "body")
```

just as an example. You will see that now everything fits (see screenshot at the bottom).

This means: your choices are in how to display the numbers (which I find the better one) or to make reductions in the size in which you are displaying the data.

---

---

[image: Screenshot of corrected R Markdown]

Comment: thanks but unfortunately that is not a work around that I want (reducing font size) and it does not solve the issue, `table 2` values are still over two lines instead of one

Comment: Unfortunately there are choices to be made here as I mentioned in my answer: changing the long mantissa of the numbers being shown, changing font sizes or others. In fact, I just did the following: I used `delete_columns(j = 2)` to get rid of that unused 2nd column. This in combination with a smaller font for the content of the cells (not the row header), opens up enough space for the line breaks to be removed in `table 2`.

Good luck with your choices!

Comment: thanks but in my example there is enough space for `table 2` to fit to the width of `table 1` without needing to worry about the choice of font size!